# TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to remove css file from head tag dynamically .I am getting this error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null**

here is is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-browser-icis7?file=/pages/index.js
[image]

```
export default function IndexPage() {
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]').forEach((item) => {
        let hrefAttr = item.getAttribute("href");
        let splitHref = hrefAttr?.split("/");
        if (splitHref[splitHref?.length - 1]?.startsWith("main")) {
          item.remove();
        }
      }, 2000);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <link href={`/main.css`} rel="stylesheet" />
      </Head>
      Hello World.{" "}
      <Link href="/about">
        <a className="red">About</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**to reproduce the bug .** : change time in setTimeout function.

Answer (score 1):

[image]The syntax to remove can be updated as below [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/remove-node-sample-h60en)

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import Head from "next/head";
import { useEffect } from "react";
export default function IndexPage() {
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]').forEach((item) => {
        let hrefAttr = item.getAttribute("href");
        let splitHref = hrefAttr?.split("/");
        if (splitHref[splitHref?.length - 1]?.startsWith("main")) {
          console.log("Remove done for ", item);
          item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
        }
      }, 1000);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <link href={`/main.css`} rel="stylesheet" />
      </Head>
      Hello World.{" "}
      <Link href="/about">
        <a className="red">About</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: still same issue

Comment: Please see the screenshot. If there is error please add the error here.